Why does canceling a CompletableFuture not actually interrupt the underlying task?
Here's a simple example:
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    CompletableFuture<Void> callbackHook = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting Runnable");
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("still running");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // why is this code never getting hit?
            System.err.println("InterruptedException caught in Runnable!");
            callbackHook.complete(null);
        }
    }, executorService);
    future.cancel(true);
    callbackHook.get(); // this hangs forever...
    System.out.println("*** DONE ***"); // this line is never reached
}

Output:
Starting Runnable
still running
still running
still running
still running
...(this continues forever)

Why so why does calling cancel(true) on the CompletableFuture not cause it to trigger an interrupt in the underlying task even though the true parameter in cancel(true) is supposed to cause it to interrupt the task?
And yes, I know this example is a bit contrived, since there's no reason why you'd necessarily want to be waiting on callbackHook instead of on future, but there are more complex cases where this sort of logic would be used - this is just a simplified example.

I voted to reopen to give more detail, but cancel(true) does not trigger an interrupt (see javadoc for parameter mayInterruptIfRunning).
However, cancelling the CF does change its isCancelled()/isDone() status. Moreover, depending on which ExecutorService you use, the underlying thread may be daemon (the default ForkJoin pool is), terminating with the JVM, while others are not (the cached thread pool you use isn't), causing the program to keep running "after" the main (tbc)

... (continued) in the end, the accepted answer of the duplicate is valid: the runnable task you gave will be executed as long as you asked it (in your case while(true)); if you want to be able to stop it somehow you'll have to handle it in the run() with external signaling (volatile boolean, semaphore, etc.).

Short answer: because CompletableFuture.cancel does not adhere to the specification of Future.cancel. The latter says: "the mayInterruptIfRunning parameter determines whether the thread executing this task should be interrupted" while the former implements: "mayInterruptIfRunning - this value has no effect in this implementation because interrupts are not used to control processing."
